# CPU time after the process finished

Tags: linux, posix, cpu-usage, timing

Is there a function in Linux which allows me to see how much CPU did a process use after it finished? I need something similar to bash "time" command. I am fork()ing the process and then waiting using wait() for a child to finish. The way of accurately measuring "real" time (actual time elapsed between fork() and exit()), even when wait() was called a long after the child process became zombie is also welcome, but I'm not sure if its possible.

Comment: Of course there is a way, or the `time` command could not work. As `man time` notes: "Most  information shown by time is derived from the wait3(2) system call." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050360/cpu-time-after-the-process-finished/7050436#7050436 gave the answer, but don't be afraid to look at the source.

Comment: On debian based systems `apt-get source time` will get you the source.

Comment: I was pretty sure, that time is a builtin feature of shell. I was calling wait() from Ruby, which seems to not have wait3 and friends wrapped in standard library. But that's not a problem as finally my Ruby extension will be written in C, now I'm just prototyping.

Comment: Many commands were historically implemented outside of the shell thus making code grovelling much less nasty. For a good time try `file /usr/bin/\[`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, [`wait3`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/wait4.2.html) and [`wait4`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/wait4.2.html) have you covered. Alternatively (and more portably) you could use [`getrusage(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrusage.2.html).

> The wait3() and wait4() system calls are similar to waitpid(2), but
>   additionally return resource usage information about the child in the
>   structure pointed to by `rusage`.

#### Example: `wait3`

```
struct rusage usage;
wait3(&status, 0, &usage);
```

#### Example: `getrusage`

Of course, `wait3` and `wait4` are just a convenience. So you could use `getrusage`:

```
getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, &usage);
```

The disadvantage is that this tells you the resources used by ALL the terminated children.

So, once you get it, what do you do with `rusage` ? `struct rusage` has the following form:

```
struct rusage {
    struct timeval ru_utime; /* user CPU time used */
    struct timeval ru_stime; /* system CPU time used */
    /* More. */
};
```

Comment: No, only a bash feature could do this in bash.   IE: If you wrote a program that did this, it would have to be the parent of the children you want info on.  That's the point of the unix "time"  command..., call it on your bash program, and it will time the program and all children.   /usr/bin/time myshell.sh

Answer (score 0):

1. The bash feature "times" reports the total user/system times used by the shell and its children.  This feature, unfortunately, doesn't report total memory, i/o etc.   IE: it doesn't  employ getrusage (which it should).
2. The /usr/bin/time program will give you executon time, memory footprint.  So you can do /usr/bin/time bash myprog.sh ... and get the accumulated times for all children.